# alternative to a foreach loop and a string builder

Tags: c#

I have a function that gets a collection of entities, and then appends quotes and commas to the string to update the collection in the DB. This is taking an insane amount of time, it's very inefficient, but I can't think of an alternative:

```
IEntityCollection c = Transactions.EvalToEntityCollection<ITransactions>(Store, key, item);

int max = transes.Count <= 750 ? transes.Count : 750;  // DB times out if there are more than 750, so 750 is the limit
int i = 0;
int t = transes.Count;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (ITransactions trans in transes)
{
    sb.Append("'");
    sb.Append(trans.GUID);
    sb.Append("',");
    i++;
    t--;

    if (i == max || t == 0)
    {
        sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);

        //in here, code updates a bunch of transactions (if <=750 transaction)

        i = 0;
        sb = new StringBuilder();
    }
}
```

Comment: [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @MattBurland Depends - does _"taking an insane amount of time"_ mean it's effectively not working.  If so, it's fine here.

Comment: One word (but that's too short so I'll fill up the comment): Parameters?

Comment: Few tips: reuse the string-builder instance (saves you a re-allocations of the internal buffer): clear it instead of creating a new one. Do not use remove on the string-builder, rearrange your algorithm so that remove is not required.

Comment: I have a feeling your "slow" part is the section you've commented out.  Have you used a profiling tool to see where most of the time is being spent?

Comment: I highly doubt the manipulation of the StringBuilder takes an insane amount of time so I would assume the problem here is the "code updates a bunch of transactions". What exactly are you doing in there?

Comment: No, the section I commented out, only goes to the DB to update the 750 or less records. This part doesn't take a very long time, I did profile it. The foreach loop is the one that is taking too long, so I need a better way of doing it. I am working with 500,000 transactions, and this runs for 2 days.

Comment: Can you show the code of the `Transactions.EvalToEntityCollection<ITransactions>(...)` method? If you are pulling lots of data in, and retrieving complete entities, and they are constructed lazily while reading the query-result, it could take a lot of time. Try to retrieve only the data you need.

Comment: Yes, I am pulling lots of data here, this is the only way I have of doing it tho:
 IEntityCollection c = Formula["Transations[TransFamily='NewBusiness' Stage=1 and TransactionID=$1 and Location=$2]"].EvalToEntityCollection<ITransactions>(Store, key, item);

So, yes one of the problems is that I retrieve an entire object each time...thanks for making me see this...I was so focused on the foreach loop that I forgot about this.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this perhaps?

```
var str = String.Join(",", transes.Select(t => string.Format("'{0}'", t.GUID)))
```

But since you have the comment in your code that it times out with `> 750` records, your "insane amount of time" might be from the database, not your code.

[String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx) is a really handy method when you want to concatenate a list of stuff together because it automatically handles the ends for you (so you don't end up with leading or trailing delimiters).

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want to do this:

1. Group the transaction numbers into batches of maximum 750 entities
2. Put all those transaction numbers in one group into one string delimited by comma and surrounded by single quotes

If so then here's the code to build the batches:

```
const int batchSize = 750;
List<List<Transaction>> batches =
    transes
    .Select((transaction, index) => new { transaction, index })
    .GroupBy(indexedTransaction => indexedTransaction.index / batchSize)
    .Select(group => group.Select(indexedTransaction => indexedTransaction.transaction).ToList())
    .ToList();
foreach (var batch in batches)
{
    // batch here is List<Transaction>, not just the GUIDs
    var guids = string.Join(", ", batch.Select(transaction => "'" + transaction.GUID + "'"));
    // process transaction or guids here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String builder is efficient. Doing it 750 times (which is your max) will definetly NOT take a measurable amount longer than any othe technique available.

Please comment out the StringBuilder part and run the project

```
sb.Append("'");
sb.Append("',");
```

I bet it will take exactly the same time to complete.